# How to read array from stdout in bash

Tags: python, bash, stdout

I am executing a python script from my bash script. The python script outputs 4 lines to stdout. I would like to store the output of these 4 lines in 4 different variables in bash or one array with 4 elements.

When I run my python script byitself I see the 4 lines on stdout:

```
$ python my_script.py
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

In my bash script I've done this:

```
OUTPUT="$(python my_script.py)"

echo "${OUTPUT}"

readarray -t y <<<"$OUTPUT"
```

After above when I do `echo $y` I only see output of first line (`line1`).

How can I use the output of python script as 4 variables or an array?

Comment: you don't need an intermediate variable: `mapfile -t y < <(python my_script.py)` is enough. Now, to output the content of the array `y` to stdout, one field per line: `printf '%s\n' "${y[@]}"` or to inspect the array: `declare -p y`.

Comment: @Anthony: Check out my logic using `read` for `bash` versions which do not support `readarray` or `maple`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$y` is the first element of the array. `${y[@]}` will give you all of them.

```
echo "${y[@]}"
```

Comment: How can I get second third etc elements of the array individually?

Comment: Yeah. `"${y[1]}"`, `"${y[2]}"`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have bash as the primary parser or have the bash shabang. This because  sh doesn't have this nice array handling...

But if you have why not create the bash array when you run the python script by the array creation parentheses? And then use Johns way to print them.

```
OUTPUT=( $(python my_script.py) )
echo "len of OUTPUT=${#OUTPUT[@]} and the data is:" ${OUTPUT[@]}
echo "Second entry is=" ${OUTPUT[1]}
```

...
...

Comment: Why not? Because it's broken: your command is subject to pathname expansion and globbing!

Comment: Is it? Where is it broken and which expansion?

Comment: Word splitting: `output=( $(echo hello world) )`. Pathname expansion: `output=( $(echo '*') )` (run from within a non-empty directory). There are lots of other counterexamples. The known ways to fix these issues is to fight _against_ the shell: alter `IFS` and use `set -f`. But it's really retarded since `mapfile`/`readarray` will do it more efficiently; moreover, that's what the OP used, so why suggest something worse than what is originally used?

Comment: The original question was how to take the output from a defined python script. Not any free defined strings or paths so why do it more complicated then necessary and do comments outside the question.

Comment: You're not using the right tool for the job (`mapfile`/`readarray` and `read` _are_ the right tool for the job), and what you're suggesting _is inherently broken._ There's nothing wrong with the fact that you suggest something wrong, as the internet is full of wrong and broken techniques regarding shell scripting and Bash, and you probably learned from them. But now you should go one step beyond what you already learned and understand why what you thought was correct is wrong, and change your habits accordingly!

Comment: Moreover, the problem in the OP is not about populating an array with the output of a command (the OP did that part properly!). The problem in the OP is that they didn't know how to inspect/output the array they populated. In the comment of OP I gave them the solution, and John Kugelman answered properly too.